# Spring Rest Web service returning 415

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have Spring web service from the following. JSON for swagger

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Extended User Management API",
    "description": "This is communicate with an extended user management webservice to test the swagger API for learning"
},
"schemes": [
    "http"
],
"basePath": "/UserManagement/rest/UserService",
"host": "127.0.0.1:8089",
"produces": [
    "application/json"
],
"consumes": [
    "application/json"
],
"paths": {
    "/users": {
        "get": {
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "An array of users",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "default": {
                    "description": "Unexpected error",
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Error"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "/addUser": {
        "post": {
            "summary": "Add an additional user",
            "description": "This service is used to add and additional user to the list of users.",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "user_id",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "Unique id of the user to be added.",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "Name of the user to be added.",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "profession",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "Profession of the user to be added.",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK"
                },
                "default": {
                    "description": "Unexpected error",
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Error"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"definitions": {
    "User": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "user_id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32",
                "description": "This is unique id that is assigned to each user."
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "This is the name of the user"
            },
            "profession": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "This is the profession that the user holds"
            }
        }
    },
    "Error": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "code": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "fields": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I generated the code and resolved all the error in the project. The I got the application to run in Spring boot main with out any problems. The issue that I'm facing now is that on accessing the get web service "/users", I'm getting an error from the service.
[image: Error produced]

I tried debugging the spring application I came to find that the intended service is not even hit. The code for service is given below.
    @javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2016-10-24T09:36:32.738Z")

```
@Api(value = "users", description = "the users API")
public interface UsersApi {

@ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "", response = User.class, responseContainer = "List", tags={  })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "An array of users", response = User.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Unexpected error", response = User.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/users",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    consumes = { "application/json" },
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<List<User>> usersGet();

}
```

Implementation of this interface is given below

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2016-10-24T09:36:32.738Z")
@Controller
public class UsersApiController implements UsersApi {

UserDao udao = new UserDao();

public ResponseEntity<List<User>> usersGet() {
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(udao.getAllUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Can please some one tell me what is the mistake that I made so that I can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are using an unsupported media type as the exception says. 
Have a look at your `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users",
produces = { "application/json" }, 
consumes = { "application/json" },
method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<List<User>> usersGet();
```

Either you remove the consumes key or you support the Content-Type in your GET request.

Edit: maybe it would be a better option to remove the consumes key. I don't think it is a good idea to consume any json in a GET request.